# How do I dynamically add one or more text boxes to a region in Oracle Apex 5.1?

Tags: javascript, plsql, textbox, oracle-apex-5.1

I am using Oracle Apex 5.1 to create a sample application.  I am trying to create new text boxes based on a number entered into a field.  So far, the actors in this play are:

- P11_TESTBOX: The text box that contains the amount of necessary new boxes
- TEST: The button that, when pressed, fires the necessary dynamic action(s)
- Procedure TEST_THIS:  PL/SQL procedure that, when triggered by the button, will run and create the necessary boxes

The procedure, as written presently (just trying to test to see if I can get it to work before implementing fully):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST_THIS (
    HOW_MANY        IN NUMBER)
IS
BEGIN
    FOR I IN 1..HOW_MANY LOOP
        HTP.P('<input class="dynamicBoxes" id="P11_BOX_' || I || '" type="text" value="" />');
        HTP.P('<br/>');
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Like normally, I set a dynamic action on TEST: Event is set to 'Click', Selection Type is 'Button', Button is 'TEST', Event Scope is 'Static'.  The True action is 'Execute PL/SQL Code', which is a simple call to the procedure `HOW_MANY`, passing :P11_TESTBOX as the number.  I kept getting the error

> Ajax call returned server error ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value
>   error for Execute PL/SQL Code

Thinking I was going crazy (which, let's be honest, isn't that far from the truth at this point), I added an 'Execute JavaScript Code' function:

```
alert(document.getElementById('P11_TESTBOX').value);
```

Not surprisingly, the number entered into the box was returned.  Sadly, the error still appeared.

In an effort to ensure I tried *everything*, I changed the syntax of the PL/SQL procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST_THIS (
    HOW_MANY        IN NUMBER)
IS
BEGIN
    FOR I IN 1..HOW_MANY LOOP
        HTP.P(
            apex_item.text(
                p_idx => 'P11_NEWBOX_0' || I,
                p_Value => ''
            )
        );
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Result:  The alert still gives me the number; the error still follows.

The idea to try both versions came from [this website](https://apextips.blogspot.com/2015/05/building-dynamic-forms.html).

Just to preempt myself, once I am able to sort this issue out, I will need to grab whatever values are entered into the created text boxes and insert them into the database.  I'm hoping that's as simple as using whatever the IDs are that get created, but I'm not optimistic after this issue.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there a reason to not use interactive gride?

Comment: Yes, though there is a likelihood that, to achieve my ultimate goal, I *can* use the interactive grid.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think htp.p only works when page is loaded, you are trying to use on a click event, I think this don't work. Try to put this code on region that execute a pl/sql code as the source.

Comment: Basically, the end result is to allow someone to create an instance of an entity that has some attributes. This entity can also have multiple versions, but the original attributes don't change with each version.  Rather than a table with five different copies of the attributes per version, the versions are a join table using the entity ID as a foreign key.

Comment: The message error is probably related of the parameter p_idx, it has to be a number. look at the documentation https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14373_01/apirefs.32/e13369/apex_item.htm#AEAPI211

Comment: I should probably have mentioned that I had been reading the docs and hadn't come to a conclusion I found satisfactory enough.  I also ran a test using htp.p to create an unordered list of one of my database tables just to see if I could get it to work in any way; this was successful.   Regarding the `p_idx`, if the variable, which is itself a number, is insufficient, then it is likely that I will have to pursue other means to achieve this goal.

Comment: Sorry, I thought the htp.p function only worked when rendering the page, if you managed to make it work in an event that does not render the page then the problem must be another one that I can not see.

Comment: Another possibility to give this error is because the value is not on a session. Next to the pl/sql code on your dynamic action there is a field "items to submit" if you not put the item P11_TESTBOX there, so the value is not passed to your procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need to write a PL/SQL Procedure. Just hide the boxes on Page Load an when triggered the button the dynamic action shows them ? So you go to Server Side Action and Item = Value and also set this in the DA